# Jenkins Docker Plugin cannot connect to Docker server host url

Tags: docker, jenkins

My Environment details as follows,

**Jenkins Master Server Details:-**

```
Jenkins Master Host OS – CentOS – 7.6
Jenkins Version - 2.164.1
Jenkins Deployed on Apache Tomcat.
Jenkins Docker Plugin Version – 1.1.6
```

**Docker Server Details:-**

```
Docker Host OS – CentOS – 7.6
Docker Version - 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
```

**Problem:**  Trying to configure Jenkins Docker plugin on Jenkins getting below errors. On Docker Host  `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file added below.

```
[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Docker Host terminal able to get output for below commands.

```
curl 100.101.102.103:2375/info
curl -XGET http://100.101.102.103:2375/containers/json
```

Whereas on Jenkins Web--> Manage Jenkins--> Configure System--> Cloud--> Docker Section connection failing.

[image]

Have tried below however not working.

```
 tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
http://127.0.0.1:2375
tcp://100.101.102.103:2375
```

Comment: Can you post more details Like:
Are Jenkins and Docker deployed on same Host ?
What is the private IP for both ?

Have you tried using tcp://PrivateIP:2375

Comment: No. Jenkins running on standalone server and Docker running on another separate standalone server. Yes I have tried with docker server private IP in Jenkins like (tcp://100.101.102.103:2375)

Comment: are you able to ping Server A from Server B and vice versa ?

Comment: Yes, on Docker host able to ping my Jenkins server private IP and On Jenkins server able to ping my docker private IP.

Comment: It should connect in that case, can you try Reloading your daemon and restart the both the services once.

Comment: From another system, can you run `DOCKER_HOST=http://100.101.102.103:2375 docker run --rm -v/:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow` to verify that Docker connectivity works, and that the daemon can correctly access the host filesystem...unauthenticated...unencrypted...with root permissions?  (You might remove that Docker daemon `-H` option, immediately, and reconsider your overall approach.)

Comment: i have executed above commands on Docker Host. First two commands worked. cat /etc/shadow file has various user details. i am using root account.

Comment: On another host also tried, DOCKER_HOST=http://100.101.102.103:2375 docker run --rm -v/:/host busybox cat /etc/shadow all three working.

Comment: Additionally Firewall disabled on both the systems.

Comment: Tried on another ubuntu docker machine command curl 100.101.102.103:2375/info it failed with curl: (7) Failed to connect to 100.101.102.103 port 2375: No route to host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed the issue. It was firewall issue. i ran `systemctl disable firewalld` command and rebooted my `CentOS-7(Docker Server)`. now connection working.